# How to use Nouveau for graphics and NVIDIA GPU for only CUDA programs on Optimus notebook?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, cuda, nouveau

I am using a notebook with a Intel i7 (with its own GPU) and a NVIDIA GPU. On Windows, the notebook uses Optimus to switch between the GPUs intelligently.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed CUDA from NVIDIA website to be able to run CUDA programs. This also installed a NVIDIA graphics driver. On booting the notebook, the kernel crashes due to a race condition with NVIDIA graphics driver module, as described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192466).

Its a kernel crash or panic everytime I boot up Ubuntu, so I cannot even get to a virtual terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+F1`) to remove the driver or fix something. I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Is there some way to let Nouveau be the graphics driver (using Intel GPU), while being able to run CUDA programs (using NVIDIA GPU)? Is there some method to install the NVIDIA, CUDA and Bumblebee packages and configure them to achieve this?

(Note: There are other similar questions, but they are answered for old versions of Ubuntu or there are no answers to them. In any case, those solutions did not work.)

Comment: did you ever get any insights on this??  I've found some perhaps useful things to try but still in process https://askubuntu.com/questions/952426/severe-under-performance-of-cuda-vs-windows-make-intel-primary-gpu

Comment: You didn't get any answers because the Intel GPU doesn't use Nouveau; Nouveau is exclusively for using NVIDIA GPUs without the proprietary NVIDIA driver. An Intel GPU would typically use the i915 driver (or in the future, the Xe driver.)

Answer (score 0):

system76-power achieves this via "compute mode." If you install [system76-power](https://github.com/pop-os/system76-power) (which is present by default in Pop!_OS, but is also available for Ubuntu via [System76's customer PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esystem76-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable), and can also be compiled and installed for some other Linux distros), you can switch to using your Intel GPU (which would actually use the i915 or Xe drivers, not Nouveau) for display and the NVIDIA card with the proprietary driver for compute only by selecting `Compute Graphics` from the battery section of the top-right menu, or by running `system76-power graphics compute` in a terminal, then rebooting.